# Directly use gnuplot from octave?

Tags: gnuplot, octave

I generally find **Octave** to be the easiest-to-use tool for data evaluation, but cumbersome for data-visualization.

On the other hand I find **Gnuplot** to be the easiest-to-use tool for data-visualization because of

- its very focused nature,
- its strong library of demo examples, and
- its comprehensive interactive help features.

These advantages are sabotaged by putting any language-wrapper between gnuplot and the user, but pure gnuplot (intentionally) lacks capabilities for doing any non-trivial preprocessing (e.g. numerical calculus).

Octave can use gnuplot as a backend, but in order to preserve the advantages I would prefer directly using gnuplot commands, say:

```
dx = 0.1;
x = 0:dx:2*pi;
y = sin(x);
y2 = cumsum(y)*dx;
outputFileName = "sin.pdf"

# Contains mockup syntax:
gp set term pdfcairo size 30cm,20cm noenhanced
gp set output '${outputFileName}'
gp plot ${x,y} using 1:2 with lines title "The sin(x) function",         \
gp      ${x,y2} using 1:2 with lines title "Integrated sin(x) function", \
gp      cos(x) title "The cos(x) function"
gprun
```

Writing a basic implementation of this "gp" utility would be easy enough, though variable interpolation would have to be replaced by explicit `gp(["set output '" outputFileName "'"])` at the cost of readability. Not so easy however would be the creation of the `${x,y}` table file.

Is there any straight-forward way to obtain similar functionality?

---

Ironically, some *much* older versions of octave (up until around 2005, 2006) had this capability (`gset`, `graw`, ...) but had them demoted to an internal implementation detail. In some older discussions I find references to e.g. `__graw__`, which also doesn't exist anymore, and some outdated documentation sites mention `gplot`, which still exists but with an entirely different purpose.

Comment: can't you write to file a gnuplot script and run it via a system command?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Yes, but then I have two scripts, and still need to deal with creating the data file for that script by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I think you're overthinking it. Creating a temporary script and running it is often even more straightforward and portable than cumbersome libraries (e.g. see my previous similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59986894/4183191) for an sqlite example )

Using that approach below works well for me, is very readable in my opinion, and does not result in unnecessary files (at least not visibly on your workspace).

```
dx = 0.1;
x  = 0 : dx : 2 * pi;
y  = sin( x );
y2 = cumsum( y ) * dx;

outputFileName = "sin.pdf"

% Create Gnuplot Script 
GPScriptName = tempname();   gp = fopen( GPScriptName, 'w');

fdisp( gp, 'set term pdfcairo size 30cm,20cm noenhanced'                         );
fdisp( gp, sprintf( 'set output "%s"', outputFileName )                          );
fdisp( gp, 'plot "-" using 1:2 with lines title "The sin(x) function", \'        );
fdisp( gp, '     "-" using 1:2 with lines title "Integrated sin(x) function", \' );
fdisp( gp, '     cos(x)                   title "The cos(x) function"'           );
fdisp( gp, [ x(:), y(:)  ]                                                       );
fdisp( gp, 'e'                                                                   );
fdisp( gp, [ x(:), y2(:) ]                                                       );
fdisp( gp, 'e'                                                                   );
fdisp( gp, ';'                                                                   );

fclose( gp )

% Run script with Gnuplot
Cmd = sprintf( 'gnuplot --persist "%s"',  GPScriptName );
[Status, Output] = system( Cmd );
```

I used 'inline' data here, so that I could dump it straight in the script (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3318865/4183191)), but if you prefer, you could use the same logic to `fdisp` them to a separate temporary Data file, and make your Gnuplot script read from that; also you may or may not handle status errors and delete the temp files after the operation (like I did in the linked sqlite example) if you're worried about producing lots of temporary files and taking up space ... but in practice it typically doesn't matter.

I think this approach is fine and gives you more control ... but, if you insist, it should be trivial to wrap those `fdisp` calls into a `gp` function, and the `system` call into a `gprun` function ...

Comment: The use of `fdisp` is a big help; I wasn't aware that such a straight-forward way for generating gnuplot-compatible data exists.