# Octave: Read BLOB data from sqlite db file

Tags: sqlite, blob, octave

I try to read BLOB data from a database file with Octave 6.2.0 and the mex-sqlite3-master package.

I am able to select and read any other data from my database file. For the column containing BLOB data it gives me the following:

octave> x=sqlite3('file.db', 'SELECT column FROM list');
error: sqlite3: unsupported column type

octave> x=sqlite3('file.db', 'SELECT column FROM list WHERE column=CAST(column AS TEXT)');
gives no error, however x with a dimension of 1x0.

The BLOB-data contains hexadecimal numbers. I am fine having them as string (and work my way further, no probs).

What can I do to extract the BLOB-data in a processable format?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: `select CAST(column AS TEXT) from bl;` is the correct form of that query. `WHERE` clause is used only to filter the results.

Comment: If you want to be sure it's not a "package" issue, you can always try using the system `sqlite3` directly, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59986894/4183191

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your answers! I tried the "select CAST(column AS TEXT) from bl;" hint. It created an array of the expected size, however with empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want:

```sql
SELECT hex(column) FROM list
```

instead of doing a CAST to TEXT.

See [Sqlite: How to cast(data as TEXT) for BLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435072/sqlite-how-to-castdata-as-text-for-blob).

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for your answer. I tried it, and it still gives me an empty array of the expected size...

Comment: Hmmm, that's surprising! I'll try to reproduce this on a sqlite setup on my box.